# passing a view to a custom swiftui container view

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm creating a custom container view in swiftui - and I want it to scale the views you put into it - but it doesn't seem to work as I'm expecting, just wondering what I'm doing wrong.

The code:

```swift
struct SplitView<Left:View, Right:View>: View
{
    
    @State var left : () -> Left
    @State var right : () -> Right
    @State var splitterWidth = 10
    @State var splitterLocation = 120
    
    var body: some View
    {
        GeometryReader()
        {
            geometry in
            HStack( spacing:0)
            {
                left().frame( width:CGFloat(splitterLocation), height: geometry.size.height)
                Text(" ").frame( width : CGFloat( splitterWidth), height : CGFloat( geometry.size.height))
                    .background(Color.yellow)
                right().frame(width: geometry.size.width - CGFloat( self.splitterWidth + self.splitterLocation), height: geometry.size.height)
                    .background(Color.red)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SplitView_Previews: PreviewProvider
{
    static var previews: some View
    {
        SplitView( left: {Text("green").background(Color.green)},
                   right: {Text("red")})
                  .frame(width:300, height:300)
    }
}
```

which produces:

[image]

I want it to scale the internal views correctly to the space allotted to them (and resize them as you drag the splitter) - but the problem is demonstrated by the background colours - the green is clearly not what is desired.   How do I a pass a view in such that I'll get the desired result (ie whatever I pass in is resized to fill the container)

Comment: All works as needed. You resized container, but colored only text. Either color a container as you do with red, or expand text, giving it maxWidth/maxHeight, before coloring.

Answer (score 0):

The effect you expected can be achieved by

```
    SplitView( 
        left: {
           Text("green")
              .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
              .background(Color.green)
        },
        right: {Text("red")}
    ).frame(width:300, height:300)
```

By default SwiftUI views intend to shrink to intrinsic content.

Comment: the thing is though - I'm not trying to colour the content - the colours are just proof that my code isn't working - I'm trying to forcibly _resize_ the content - that's the point of the container - I want whatever is in the left pane to be force to the size of the pane.

Comment: This is not the way how SwiftUI works. For example, having `VStack { Text("") }`, you can resize VStack, container, by applying `.frame`, but Text inside remains with own size, because the modifier, `.frame`, is applied _only_ to exact view it is attached to.